# Insert from DataGridView to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to insert data to a SQL Server with a dataGridView.
Here's what I have now in my buttonSave_Click :

```
string conString = "xxxxxxxx";
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
{
    con.Open();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewStock.Rows)
    {
        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO stock_test(size,quantity,codeArticleComponent) VALUES (@size,@quantity,@codeArticleComponent)", con);
        if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[1].Value != null)
        {
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", row.Cells[0].Value);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", row.Cells[1].Value);
            insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeArticleComponent", labelComponentChosen.Text);
        }
        insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        insert.Parameters.Clear();
    }
```

For now this piece of code has a weird behavior because it throws an exception `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Must declare the scalar variable "@size"` but what I wrote in the cells is still added to the database.

Comment: Why not just write row.Cells[0].Value directly into your values script?

Comment: @plaidDK, by writing row.Cells[0].Value directly into values script, you are creating sql-injection vulnerability

Comment: @ASh How come? there can only be one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very likely command cannot be executed on last DataGridView row, which is reserved for new item input. and all previous items are inserted properly.

it happens because `(row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[1].Value != null)` check for that row returns `false` and parameters are not added. the next statement `insert.ExecuteNonQuery();` tries to run a command without required parameters and fails

create and execute `insert` command only for valid rows:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewStock.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[1].Value != null)
    {
        SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO stock_test(size,quantity,codeArticleComponent) VALUES (@size,@quantity,@codeArticleComponent)", con);

        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", row.Cells[0].Value);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", row.Cells[1].Value);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeArticleComponent", labelComponentChosen.Text);

        insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 string conString = "xxxxxxxx";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewStock.Rows)
        {
            SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand();

            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null && row.Cells[1].Value != null)
            {
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@size", row.Cells[0].Value);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", row.Cells[1].Value);
                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@codeArticleComponent", labelComponentChosen.Text);
            }
            insert = ("INSERT INTO stock_test(size,quantity,codeArticleComponent) VALUES (@size,@quantity,@codeArticleComponent)", con);
            insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
            insert.Parameters.Clear();
        }
```

The Error is occur as you are using the variable before declaring them. Please Declare them prior with value before using into the Query.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlCommand sCommand;
        SqlDataAdapter sAdapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder sBuilder;
        DataSet sDs;
        DataTable sTable;        

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=pubs;Integrated Security=True";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM Stores";
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            connection.Open();
            sCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand);
            sBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
            sDs = new DataSet();
            sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Stores");
            sTable = sDs.Tables["Stores"];
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables["Stores"];
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            save_btn.Enabled = false;
            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        }

        private void new_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
            save_btn.Enabled = true;
            new_btn.Enabled = false;
            delete_btn.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void delete_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to delete this row ?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                sAdapter.Update(sTable);
            }
        }

        private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sAdapter.Update(sTable);
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
            save_btn.Enabled = false;
            new_btn.Enabled = true;
            delete_btn.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can find LOTS of great examples from the link below.

http://csharp.net-informations.com/datagridview/csharp-datagridview-database-operations.htm